# How do I implement a single, shared background image for an Actionbar and tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I'm aware of using styles and themes for adjusting my Actionbar and tabs, but what I haven't been able to discover is a way to have a single image as a background for both of them, as opposed to one image being used once in the Actionbar and once again for every tab. I want them all to share a static background.

Here is a rough mockup of what I'm envisioning. Can this be done without having to resort to a faux Actionbar and tabs? Additionally, could I bleed into the status bar?

[image: Mockup of Actionbar and Tabs sharing a background image]

Answer (score 1):

For the actionBar color, I suggest you use the `Android asset studio` [here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100). It's a easy way to change the actionBar color and style. All you need to do is generate the style you want, download zip file, unzip it, copy all files (drawable folders) into your `res` folder and `change your app theme` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to what you just generated from `asset studio`.